# Cant Ping from one specific Pi to other devices including other Pi's on the same Wi-Fi network

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

Ive got several Pi's on the same Wi-Fi network but one in particular is causing some networking grief. Its connected with an IP address and I can see it on my Wi-Fi router. I can remote desktop into it. I can also get an internet connection and browse to various websites. However when I try to ping to it from another Pi or ping to another Pi from it the command line just freezes and nothing happens. I can ping websites such as google.co.uk no problem. I can also ping localhost ok along with its hostname but any other IP address on the same network just dosen't seem to work. I have been trying to connect a simple Python MQTT script from this Pi hence why I need to get it working but even from the Python script it does not want to make an outgoing connection.

Other Pi's on the same network are working fine with no problems as above. Just this one.

Any ideas or suggestions?

cheers.

results from ifconfig:

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.199  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::b523:e8ac:5dd4:53a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a00:23c6:9c81:df01:df79:9d93:5f3c:2180  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:0f:00:75:4e:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21832  bytes 4719166 (4.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8439  bytes 4475348 (4.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please edit in the output from `ip route`.

Comment: are the other pi's also connected using wifi?

Comment: yes all other Pi's are on the same Wi-Fi network.

Comment: ip route default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.199 metric 303 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.199 metric 303